# When to use "gibt es / es gibt"?

Tags: usage

I see "gibt es" / "es gibt" being used in so many phrases. But I am not able
to understand under what circumstances this is used? What I understand is that it cannot be directly related to English language sentence formation (i.e it gives).
For example:

> Es gibt einen Stau und er ist zu spät.

(*It gives traffic and he is late*, which is actually: "There is a traffic and hence he is late.")

When speaking, what makes you to use "es gibt" and if anyone can give co-relation to English, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

"Is there / there is" should work the same way in English.

Comment: Most times, but you still need to consider that in English the subject is always preceding the verb except for questions. In German the word order may change more often.

Comment: I was only talking about the phrase "there is" = "es gibt". Obviously the rest of the sentence needs to be grammatical as well. As to "the subject *always* preceding the verb, except for questions": There are no rules without exceptions (including this one).